# error on doing "Truffle init"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am new to smart contract programming, recently installed truffle using npm on Node(version: 6.10.3)
When I run the command `truffle init` first time, I received this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.8.133:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

The next time I run `truffle init`, I got ths error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

Any idea on how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing a similar issue when I tried to execute truffle init behind a corporate http proxy and found a workaround.

Modified the cli.bundled.js: replaced https.request with [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Diff:

```
    diff --git a/build/cli.bundled.js b/build/cli.bundled.js
    index 01c69e3..aa2605c 100755
    --- a/build/cli.bundled.js
    +++ b/build/cli.bundled.js
    @@ -202412,12 +202412,8 @@ var Init = {
           // will fail spectacularly in a way we can't catch, so we have to do it ourselves.
           return new Promise(function(accept, reject) {

    -        var options = {
    -          method: 'HEAD',
    -          host: 'raw.githubusercontent.com',
    -          path: '/trufflesuite/' + expected_full_name + "/master/truffle.js"
    -        };
    -        req = https.request(options, function(r) {
    +        var request = require('request');
    +        request({ method: 'HEAD', uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trufflesuite/'+expected_full_name+'/master/truffle.js'}, function (error, r, body) {
               if (r.statusCode == 404) {
                 return reject(new Error("Example '" + name + "' doesn't exist. If you believe this is an error, please contact Truffle support."));
               } else if (r.statusCode != 200) {
    @@ -202425,7 +202421,6 @@ var Init = {
               }
               accept();
             });
    -        req.end();

           });
         }).then(function() {
    @@ -212634,4 +212629,4 @@ module.exports = require("solc");
     module.exports = require("string_decoder");

     /***/ })
    -/******/ ]);
    \ No newline at end of file
    +/******/ ]);
```

Prerequisite:

1. Install request via npm (npm install -g request)
2. Proxy - setup enviroment as described [here](https://github.com/request/request#proxies)

Comment: soo... no way to init truffle behind proxy without modifying source code?????????????????

Comment: @EralpB I have not been able to find any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Without code it is pretty difficult to say where this goes wrong. But do you have a ethereum rpc node running on the port specified in the truffle configuration.

[Truffle configuration](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)

When inspecting your error code I see you try to connect to 151.101.8.133:443 is there an rpc node running on this port?

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: Thanks link is fixed.